# How do I pass in `Option<MyEnum>` as an argument when testing

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, javascript

I have a functions looks somewhat like this in the program

```
enum DummyState {
  one,
  two
}

fn dummy(ctx: Context<Dummy>, state: Option<DummyState>) {
...
}
```

How do I pass in the arguments to the function?

The snipped below does not work.

```
await program.methods
       .dummy({ one: {} })
       .accounts({
           user: user.publicKey,
           state: statePDA,
       })
       .signers([user])
       .rpc();
```

I get this error instead.
`Error: unable to infer src variant`

Answer (score 3):

I cannot replicate the issue. I was able to pass `null` when I did not have an argument to pass. Happy to take a look at your full code if you have a GH.

Here's what I tested (and `anchor test` ran fine):

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("6itiTNjzVZWxSgrjaGwMMjakDvrmnkwPG5YsbiU2jSkX");

#[program]
mod enum_test {
    use super::*;
    pub fn dummy(_ctx: Context<Dummy>, _data: Option<DummyState>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Dummy<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum DummyState {
    One,
    Two,
}
```

And my test:

```
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { EnumTest } from "../target/types/enum_test";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("enum-test", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
  const program = anchor.workspace.EnumTest as Program<EnumTest>;
  // Reusable function to test dummy calls
  async function testDummyCall(dummyArgs: any) {
    try {
      const tx = await program.methods.dummy(dummyArgs).rpc();
      expect(tx).to.be.ok;
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).to.not.be.ok;
    }
  }

  it("Is dummy one!", async () => {
    await testDummyCall({ one: {} });
  });

  it("Is dummy two!", async () => {
    await testDummyCall({ two: {} });
  });

  it("Is not a dummy!", async () => {
    await testDummyCall(null);
  });

  it("Fails on dummy three!", async () => {
    try {
      await program.methods.dummy({ three: {} }).rpc();
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).to.be.ok;
    }
  });
});
```